# RoR user contact employee relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Devise, so I have a user table.
I have added an Employee table and a Contact table (customer contacts).
Each Employee and Contact will have their own user_id.

What would be the best approach for setting up the table relationships?

1) Have the Employee and Contact belong_to :user?

2) Polymorphic?

Thanks

Update =============

I changed the code as Yosep said.

But, I can't figure out how to display fields from the employee record in an index list of users. For example, the list(index) of users, should contain employee.first_name. I tried this =

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.id%></td>
    <td><%= Employee.where(:user_id => user.id).first_name %> </td><td><%=
```

and I tried this:

```
<td><%= Employee.find_by_user_id(user).first_name %> </td> code
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :contacts
```

Once you do this, you could do magical things like:

```
employees = User.find(1).employees
```

Comment: In my model the user is either one employee or one contact.  Should I use has_one in the class User?